# waitpid/wexitstatus returning 0 instead of correct return code

Tags: c++, c, linux, waitpid, wexitstatus

I have the helper function below, used to execute a command and get the return value on posix systems. I used to use `popen`, but it is impossible to get the return code of an application with `popen` if it runs and exits before `popen`/`pclose` gets a chance to do its work.

The following helper function creates a process fork, uses `execvp` to run the desired external process, and then the parent uses `waitpid` to get the return code. I'm seeing odd cases where it's refusing to run.

When called with `wait` = `true`, `waitpid` should return the exit code of the application no matter what. However, I'm seeing `stdout` output that specifies the return code should be non-zero, yet the return code is zero. Testing the external process in a regular shell, then `echo`ing `$?` returns non-zero, so it's not a problem w/ the external process not returning the right code. If it's of any help, the external process being run is `mount(8)` (yes, I know I can use `mount(2)` but that's besides the point).

I apologize in advance for a code dump. Most of it is debugging/logging:

```
inline int ForkAndRun(const std::string &command, const std::vector<std::string> &args, bool wait = false, std::string *output = NULL)
{
    std::string debug;

    std::vector<char*> argv;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < args.size(); ++i)
    {
        argv.push_back(const_cast<char*>(args[i].c_str()));
        debug += "\"";
        debug += args[i];
        debug += "\" ";
    }
    argv.push_back((char*)NULL);

    neosmart::logger.Debug("Executing %s", debug.c_str());

    int pipefd[2];

    if (pipe(pipefd) != 0)
    {
        neosmart::logger.Error("Failed to create pipe descriptor when trying to launch %s", debug.c_str());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(pipefd[STDIN_FILENO]); //child isn't going to be reading
        dup2(pipefd[STDOUT_FILENO], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(pipefd[STDOUT_FILENO]); //now that it's been dup2'd
        dup2(pipefd[STDOUT_FILENO], STDERR_FILENO);

        if (execvp(command.c_str(), &argv[0]) != 0)
        {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else if (pid < 0)
    {
        neosmart::logger.Error("Failed to fork when trying to launch %s", debug.c_str());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else
    {
        close(pipefd[STDOUT_FILENO]);

        int exitCode = 0;

        if (wait)
        {
            waitpid(pid, &exitCode, wait ? __WALL : (WNOHANG | WUNTRACED));

            std::string result;
            char buffer[128];
            ssize_t bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = read(pipefd[STDIN_FILENO], buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1)) != 0)
            {
                buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';
                result += buffer;
            }

            if (wait)
            {
                if ((WIFEXITED(exitCode)) == 0)
                {
                    neosmart::logger.Error("Failed to run command %s", debug.c_str());
                    neosmart::logger.Info("Output:\n%s", result.c_str());
                }
                else
                {
                    neosmart::logger.Debug("Output:\n%s", result.c_str());
                    exitCode = WEXITSTATUS(exitCode);
                    if (exitCode != 0)
                    {
                        neosmart::logger.Info("Return code %d", (exitCode));
                    }
                }
            }

            if (output)
            {
                result.swap(*output);
            }
        }

        close(pipefd[STDIN_FILENO]);

        return exitCode;
    }
}
```

Note that the command is run OK with the correct parameters, the function proceeds without any problems, and `WIFEXITED` returns `TRUE`. However, `WEXITSTATUS` returns 0, when it should be returning something else.

Comment: You should check the return codes of your system calls. The call `dup2(pipefd[STDOUT_FILENO], STDERR_FILENO);` will fail with [EBADF] and the `waitpid()` likely fails as well (what's the `__WALL` for?). Also, you should read the output before waiting for the process to avoid deadlock if the output is larger than the buffering in the pipe. Furthermore, some of the checks on `wait` are redundant.

Comment: Your assumption that the elements in a `std::vector` are contiguous in memory is incorrect. The C++ standard developers instead chose to guarantee that `push_back` does not change the address of existing elements. I suggest creating an array of `char *` instead but there may be more STL tricks.

Comment: @jilles C++03 and C++11 guarantee contiguous memory allocation for `vector`, no?

Comment: I agree, I thought that was by-design to allow inter-operability with existing system calls that needed char buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the [mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) library, and grepping my code for `SIGCHLD` revealed that using `mg_start` from mongoose results in setting `SIGCHLD` to `SIG_IGN`.

From the [`waitpid` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid), on Linux a `SIGCHLD` set to `SIG_IGN` will not create a zombie process, so `waitpid` will fail if the process has already successfully run and exited - but will run OK if it hasn't yet. This was the cause of the sporadic failure of my code.

Simply re-setting `SIGCHLD` after calling `mg_start` to a void function that does absolutely nothing was enough to keep the zombie records from being immediately erased.

Per [@Geoff_Montee's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13182422/17027), there was a bug in my redirect of `STDERR`, but this was not responsible for the problem as `execvp` does not store the return value in `STDERR` or even `STDOUT`, but rather in the kernel object associated with the parent process (the zombie record).

[@jilles' warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182100/waitpid-wexitstatus-returning-0-instead-of-correct-return-code/13182422#comment17941630_13182100) about non-contiguity of `vector` in C++ does not apply for C++03 and up (only valid for C++98, though in practice, most C++98 compilers did use contiguous storage, anyway) and was not related to this issue. However, the advice on reading from the pipe before blocking and checking the output of `waitpid` is spot-on.

Answer (score 2):

Probably isn't your main issue, but I think I see a small problem. In your child process, you have...

```
dup2(pipefd[STDOUT_FILENO], STDOUT_FILENO);
close(pipefd[STDOUT_FILENO]); //now that it's been dup2'd
dup2(pipefd[STDOUT_FILENO], STDERR_FILENO); //but wait, this pipe is closed!
```

But I think what you want is:

```
dup2(pipefd[STDOUT_FILENO], STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(pipefd[STDOUT_FILENO], STDERR_FILENO);
close(pipefd[STDOUT_FILENO]); //now that it's been dup2'd for both, can close
```

I don't have much experience with forks and pipes in Linux, but I did write a similar function pretty recently. You can take a look at the code to compare, if you'd like. I know that my function works.

[execAndRedirect.cpp](http://pastebin.com/BTZ2R2dK)

Comment: You're right, that is going to fail. But I don't think that's the cause, the exit code is not conveyed via `stdout` or `stderr`.

Comment: Well, fixing that didn't change matters. waitpid is failing with `ECHILD`, though the PID it is being given is quite valid. Also, @jilles' comment about contiguity is incorrect for C++03 and C++11.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Upvoting this suggestion for finding a bug in the code, but ultimately it was not the core issue.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi glad to help. And glad you discovered the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that `pclose` does NOT block and wait for the process to end, contrary to the documentation (this is on CentOS 6).  I've found that I need to call `pclose` and then call `waitpid(pid,&status,0);` to get the true return value.